# Rails 4.0 undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, actioncontroller

I'm trying to add a line to my `orders_items` controller so if its a new order to increment the counter from zero to one. so have created an action that does that before the save is called but when I try it I get:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

```ruby
def create
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])
    # Error below
    @order_item.quantity += 1

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order_item.save
    end
end
```

`order_item.rb`:

```ruby
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :product

    validates :order_id, :product, presence: true
    validates :quantity, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }

    def subtotal
    quantity * product.price
  end
end
```

`order_items_controller.rb`:

```ruby
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order_item, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy]
  before_action :load_order, only: [:create]

  # GET /order_items
  # GET /order_items.json
  def index
    @order_items = OrderItem.all
  end

  # GET /order_items/new
  def new
    @order_item = OrderItem.new
  end

  # POST /order_items
  # POST /order_items.json
  def create
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])
    @order_item.quantity += 1

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Successfully added product to cart.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /order_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /order_items/1.json
  def update
      @order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
          if order_item_params[:quantity].to_i == 0
             @order_item.destroy

             format.html { redirect_to @order_item.order, notice: 'Order item was successfully updated.' }
             format.json { head :no_content }

        elsif @order_item.update(order_item_params)

            format.html { redirect_to @order_item.order, notice: 'Successfully updated the order item.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @order_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
        end
      end
  end

  # DELETE /order_items/1
  # DELETE /order_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @order_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @order_item.order }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    def load_order
        @order = Order.find_or_initialize_by_id(session[:order_id], status: "unsubmitted")
        if @order.new_record?
            @order.save!
            session[:order_id] = @order.id
        end
    end

    def set_order_item
      @order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_item_params
      params.require(:order_item).permit(:product_id, :order_id, :quantity)
    end
end
```

Migration file:

```ruby
class AddDefaultQuantityToOrderItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :order_items, :quantity, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

`rails console`:

```
@order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])
NoMethodError: undefined method `order_items' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Model `order.rb`:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy

  def total
    order_items.map(&:subtotal).sum
  end

end
```

`orders_controller.rb`:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, :status)
    end
end
```

Update

Rake routes shows route call for /:product_id

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_numericality_of :price
    validates :stock ,numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to:  0 }
end
```

order.rb

```
# @Chiperific added proper 4-line indentation for SO viewing.
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :product

    validates :order_id, :product, presence: true
    validates :quantity, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }


    def subtotal
    quantity * product.price
  end
end
```

order items.rb

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :product

validates :order_id, :product, presence: true
validates :quantity, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }


def subtotal
    quantity * product.price
    end
end
```

when i add

```
def create
  @order_item = OrderItems.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])
  @order_item.quantity +=1
```

i get NameError in OrderItemsController#create -  uninitialized constant OrderItemsController::Orderitems

def create
    @order_item = Orderitems.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id]) <-error
    @order_item.quantity += 1

if i try

```
@order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  @order_item = @order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])
  @order_item.quantity += 1
```

i get ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in OrderItemsController#create - Couldn't find Order without an ID

```
def create
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])<-error 
    @order_item.quantity += 1
```

Comment: I guess your quantity is not starting with 0. Try using a debugger, and step through or create an order item from the console to see if quantity is starting with 0 from the get go. Just to double check, your migration has been run and server has been restarted?

Comment: `@order_item.quantity` is not defined.  You might need to initialize it

Comment: Is there a chance your `@order_item` existed BEFORE the default was set up on your database schema?  My guess is, it does so if you ran in rails console `@order_item.quantity` it would result in `nil` and not `0`

Comment: @Anthony: Bapically with the migration it should be ok. When the migration is done, all `quantity` present on your table `order_items` have been initialized to 0. I think the problem comes from the `@order_item` itself. Did you try `@order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])` directly on your console ?

Comment: @bobbystouket Some databases (Postgres, for instance) don't automatically assign newly updated default values to existing column entries.  He would need to do `OrderItem.all` and see if any quantities were not set to zero after that migration and manually fix them.

Comment: @Neil Where are you defining `@order`?

Comment: yes i ran Order.destroy_all and OrderItem.destroy_all before doing this

Comment: @Neil, I'm pretty confident your issue is not with `@order_item.quantity`. In the `irb`, I think you'll find that `@order` is `nil`

Comment: @Neil, did defining `@order` solve the problem?

Comment: @Chiperific hi tried both your methods and got uninitialized constant OrderItemsController::OrderItems and the 2nd method got Couldn't find Order without an ID

Comment: @Neil, what is the url of the view? See the update to my answer.

Comment: @Chiperific added comments

Comment: @Neil, please see the `accepts_nested_attributes` section of my answer and implement in your models.

Answer (score 2):

I don' t see where `@order` is defined. Since `@order` is null, `@order_items` will be as well.

I'm assuming your view URL is something like `/orders/:order_id/order_items/:id`
So let's use the URL parameter to make sure you get an `Order` or `Order_ID` initiated.

### Option 1: Don't worry about @order

```
def create
  @order_item = OrderItem.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])
  @order_item.quantity +=1

  ...

end
```

---

### Option 2: Set the `@order` first

```
def create
  @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  @order_item = @order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])
  @order_item.quantity += 1

  ...

end
```

---

### Other potential problem:

`.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])` isn't actually *finding* or *initializing*.

It looks like this is your table relationship:

``````
[Orders]`````\
              |--> [Order_Items]
[Products]___/
``````

1. I don't see where you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items` in `orders.rb`
2. You probably also need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items` in `products.rb`
3. Does an `Order_Item` record have a `Product_id` field? I see where you're validating the presence of `:product`, but not `:product_id`, what does your schema look like? What happens if you try `find__or_initialize_by_product(params[:product_id])
4. Does your route call for `/:product_id` or `/:product` or neither? (a.k.a. is there a `params[:product_id]`?)

## Update:

Thanks for the updated comments. Please add the whole URI being used, the whole Rake Routes line, or the Routes.rb file.
Or, while I know it's not SO-best-practice, you could post a link to the project on Github and I'll take a look there.

I'm still convinced that (at least one of) the issue(s) is that @order is not being set.

**Trying it out in the Rails console is a great way to find out of `.find_or_initialize_by_product_id` is working**

But, rails console can’t pull params and you still aren’t assigning @order first.
To test, in the rails console, try:

```
@order = Order.first #<----(just so you get @order assigned)
@order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(1)
```

Also:

```
@order_item = OrderItems.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])
```

`OrderItems` should be singular (my bad!!):

```
@order_item = OrderItem.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])
```

I'll pay closer attention to this post and be more timely with my posts as I'm sure you're getting frustrated. Hang in there, your methodology is good.

But, there may be another way if we can't get these kinks worked out. Could we find the order item quantity by counting the # of records with a specific order id instead of saving the number statically in the database? Just a thought if you're ready to bail on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize @order_item.quantity by putting this in your OrderItem class:

```
def quantity
  self.quantity ||= 0
end
```

Comment: This is not the issue. Quantity is being intialized at 0 from the schema.

Comment: @Chiperific you are wrong, this is exactly the issue. There is no initializing of quantity from within the shown ruby code. It is enforced when saving, and may be enforced on the schema, but when a new `OrderItem` is created `quantity` is nil. This is also exactly what the error states: `+ is not defined for nil` so quantity is nil. This is a very clean solution, another alternative would be to add an `after_initialize` on the model to explicitly set quantity to 0 if nil. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: So why is the OP getting this error regardless of whether it's a new record or not?

Answer (score 0):

Go into your method `find_or_initialize_by_product_id`, and make sure you initialize the attribute `quantity` to 0.

Here's a simple reproduction of your error - notice I never initialized `x` to 0:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> x += 5
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: @order_item is defined, on the line previous.

Comment: You're right - I meant to say "quantity" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 you can use the following:

```
@order_item = @order.order_items.where(product_id: params[:product_id]).first_or_create
```

instead of

```
@order_item = @order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by_product_id(params[:product_id])
```

and this:

```
@order = Order.where(session[:order_id], status: "unsubmitted").first_or_initialize
```

instead of

```
@order = Order.find_or_initialize_by_id(session[:order_id], status: "unsubmitted")
```